# X11 graphics context not rendering anything

Tags: x11

I've been looking through the Xlib docs attempting to create a simple XWindows application. I'm able to get a window up and running, modify its background colour using pixel colours, etc.

Unfortunately, when I try and create a graphics content and render some of the primitives (Rectangles/Arcs etc) nothing is rendered.

I then built and ran the example [here](http://neuron-ai.tuke.sk/hudecm/Tutorials/C/special/xlib-programming/simple-drawing.c) to make sure I wasn't missing something and it also just rendered the background with none of the primitives.

Can anyone explain what I may be missing here?

If it matters I'm running Fedora 23 on kernel 4.4.1 using Gnome shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event loop and move your drawing to occur after you receive expose event ( also make sure you set event mask when you create window or with XSelectInput call ). Likely the result of your drawing is disposed at some point and because you don't react to "window are is damaged, need to re-paint" notification all you see is window background

Take a look at this [example](http://math.msu.su/~vvb/2course/Borisenko/CppProjects/GWindow/hi.c)